# Position fixed input

Tags: input, position, fixed

I have a `<input type="button" />` and a `<input type="text" />`

[image]

How can I put the plus to the left of the textbox so that it will always be there, no matter the zoom made on the browser...?

Comment: Where is the code that has gotten you this far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put both the controls in a `<div>` tag.. and set the width of the div, so that it always remain of a fixed size, independent of the browser's zoom.

And then apply css to the button as: `#buttonID { float:left; }`